# HTML binding in Angular 8

Tags: html, css, typescript, plot, angular8

I am unable to display html content to Angular 8.

**Note: I am receiving html template which I need to display on Angular is coming from database as a JSON, which I am fetching it and saving it to a variable (e.g, plot) and then passing that variable to `this.myTemplate = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.plot)`

For demo purpose I put a sample html template similar to my data which I am getting it from database.

HTML:

```
<div [innerHTML]="myTemplate"></div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core'; 
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-decomposition',
  templateUrl: './data-decomposition.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-decomposition.component.css']

})

export class DataDecompositionComponent implements OnInit {

myTemplate:SafeHtml;

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

this.myTemplate = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
<p>plot come below...</>
    <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  var data = [
    {
      x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
      y: [20, 14, 23],
      type: 'bar'
    }
  ];

  Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);

  </script>
  </body>
  </html>`);

}
```

When I run the code only the `<p>` tag content "Plot come below.." is displaying to the Angular front-end but the Plotly chart which is inside `<script>` tag is not displaying. Can anyone suggest me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Take your scripts tags to index.html. In your component, you can't reach script tags.Also don't forget to close

tag correctly :)

```
<script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = [
    {
      x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
      y: [20, 14, 23],
      type: 'bar'
    }
  ];

  Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);

  </script>
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-83tffr

Comment: Ok. but the issue for me is that above html template which I am passing inside this.myTemplate = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('html code') is coming from back-end as a JSON and in that case I can not place script tag inside index.html, what will be your solution then. please give your opinion on this scenario

Answer (score 0):

It wont work.
First you are trying to put an entire HTML Page inside a div.
Second, you should first start the scripts,in your component, then load the html

in the component html. you can put in app.component.html or any other component you create in Angular. I would suggest you to create a new one and import in your app-component

```
<p>plot come below...</>
    <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
```

if you cant put the script in index.html as suggested by Çağrı TAÇYİLDİZ

or try this method:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core'; 
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-decomposition',
  templateUrl: './data-decomposition.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-decomposition.component.css']

})

export class DataDecompositionComponent implements OnInit {


constructor() { }

   public loadScript(url) {
        let node = document.createElement('script');
        node.src = url;
        node.type = 'text/javascript';
        node.async = true;
        node.charset = 'utf-8';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
    }


ngOnInit(){
  this.loadScript('https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js');
}


}
```

the script tag you can put inside /data-decomposition.component.html, but i suggest you to put on your index.html, or.. you can save a new js file, and import in the index.html, or use the loadScript method in the class to import it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = [
    {
      x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
      y: [20, 14, 23],
      type: 'bar'
    }
  ];

  Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);

  </script>
```